# How display dynamic layout in java swing form config file

Tags: java, swing

```
 <Panel AutoScroll ="false" AutoSize="true" Column="2" ColumnSpan="3" Row="4" RowSpan="1" Category="INPUT">
      <MaximumSize Height="0" Width="0"/>
      <MinimumSize Height="0" Width="0"/>
      ...
      <Size Height="120" Width="389"/>
      ...
      <CellBorderStyle>None</CellBorderStyle>
      <Dock>Left</Dock>
      <Anchor>Top,Left</Anchor>

    </Panel>
```

I have a element in config file:
I want to load a JPanel in java swing. In java, I set

```
GridBagConstraints layout = new GridBagConstraints();    
layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
layout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
```

And I added into Jpanel, I see both panel and controls in panel shift to the left. But attribute ColumnSpan="3". 
I hope panel will fill full, so I use:

```
layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
layout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
```

when, all controls in panel were fill full,

Who can help me resolve this problem

My code:

```
loadDynamicPanel(List<PanelType> pannels, JPanel mainPanel, JFramFram form)
    {
        JPanel tempPanel = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < pannels.size(); j++)
        {
            PanelType panelType = pannels.get(j);
            tempPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
            layout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            layout.gridx = panelType.getColumn() != null ? panelType.getColumn() : 0;
            layout.gridy = panelType.getRow() != null ? panelType.getRow() : 0;
            layout.gridheight =  panelType.getRowSpan();
            layout.gridwidth =panelType.getColumnSpan();        

            TitledBorder border = new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

            tempPanel.setBorder(border);

            tempPanel.setSize(panelType.getSize().getWidth(), panelType.getSize().getHeight());

            mainPanel.add(tempPanel, layout);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fill will fill allow the component to "fill" the available space of the "cell"

Comment: I want panel will full and components will shift to left, How? Please help me

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You can see my code above and help me